# Selenium + ChromeDriver no such attribute execute.script to WebElement

Tags: python, selenium

so I've been searching online how to make my selenium taskbot scroll..

So people say to use driver.execute_script("JS exec;")
However my Selenium only recognizes a driver._execute() command however it gives me a KeyError for the JS execution..

I was wondering if I need to import an extra dependency or something?

These are all my dependencies..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import math
import random
```

I'm trying this:

```
    try:
        randfollower = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{c}]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a')
        randfollower.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        followscroller = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]')
        followscroller.**_execute**("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")
```

selenium only recognizes the "_execute" but not the "execute_script" syntax, however the "_execute" one gives me a KeyError

This is the error code I get:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/IGBOT/bot.py", line 176, in <module>
    randomfollowchoose()
  File "C:/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/IGBOT/bot.py", line 95, in randomfollowchoose
    followscroller._execute("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")
  File "C:\Users\jason\PycharmProjects\IGBOT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\jason\PycharmProjects\IGBOT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\jason\PycharmProjects\IGBOT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 367, in execute
    command_info = self._commands[command]
KeyError: 'window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)'
```

Comment: You may need to use `driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute_script` is not defined at the element level. You should use `webdriver` instance to execute the script as shown below.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")
```

Comment: Hey, driver.execute_script works, however I'm not targeting the page's scroll, I'm targeting a pop up box's scrolling, thus the use of "followerscroller" to define the little pop up box as the object that will be scrolled.. is there a way I can execute_script on that instead of the page as a whole?

Comment: You can get the element and scroll it rather `window`. You have to change the line as `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,200);",element)`. FYI, this will scroll the element by 200 px.